# I have a 2d array. Need to make a loop to replace first 2 rows, then next 2 only rows and so on by ones and print till the loop ends

Tags: python, numpy

```
b = np.random.randint(0,10, (6,3))
```

I tried this code, but it gives the `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) () (6,3)

```
step = 2
r1 = 0
r2 = 2

while r2 <= len(b):
    c = np.where(b[r1:r2] >= 0, 1, b)   
    print(c)
    r1+ = step
    r2+ = step
```

I think the problem is in a condition of `np.where`. It creates an array wih a shape that is incompatible with `b` array
What i need is for the code to receive array b and to return 3 arrays of the same size of b but with two rows been substituted by 1´s. Like this:

```
[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [6 3 4]
 [2 9 3]
 [6 9 2]
 [8 1 0]]
[[3 2 8]
 [3 8 5]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [6 9 2]
 [8 1 0]]
[[3 2 8]
 [3 8 5]
 [6 3 4]
 [2 9 3]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]]
```

My tutor told me to try it with 'np.where' function.But it seems that this function doesnt support this type of condition i´m trying to feed to it. May be there is another way to get the desired output. All examples I googled work with random values of the array and not precisely rows. In pandas it easier. But i need numpy code to feed the output to the neural network. The ones will be treated by it as an empty values, but the size of the array will be always the same, thus not producing errors

Comment: Please provide an example input and the expected output.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The output of the code should be like above. 3 arrays of the same size as 'b' array and each having two rows substituted by 1´s

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `ValueError` because the size of `b[0:2]` is not the same as the size of `b`.

```
print(b.shape)
# (6, 3)
print(b[0:2].shape)
# (2, 3)
```

The [documentation for `numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) states that the way the condition works is "Where True, yield x, otherwise yield y." Thus, you need to be able to broadcast x and y onto the size of your condition. In your example, you can't broadcast (6,3) onto (2,3) and hence the error.

You need things to be the same size. For example, `c = np.where(b[0:2] >= 0, 1, b[0:2])` would not give you an error.

However, if you want to step through your array `b`, then you need something other than `b[0:2]`. Otherwise it will just keep repeating that first part your array. I think you probably want `b[r1:r2]`.

Also, I notice that you have `r1+ = step` instead of `r1 += step`, which will also spit out an error. Note that you don't actually need both `r1` and `r2` since their offset is `step`.

Putting all this together, we can adjust your code to give you something that works:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.random.randint(0,5, (6,3))
step = 2
r1 = 0

while r1 <= len(b) - step:
    c = np.copy(b)
    c[r1:r1+step] = np.where(b[r1:r1+step] >= 0, 1, b[r1:r1+step])   
    print(c)
    r1 += step
```

Or you could instead do it with a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.random.randint(0,5, (6,3))
step = 2


for r1 in range(0, len(b), step):
    c = np.copy(b)
    c[r1:r1+step] = np.where(b[r1:r1+step] >= 0, 1, b[r1:r1+step])   
    print(c)
```

Resulting output:

```
[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [3 2 2]
 [1 1 2]
 [3 3 0]
 [3 2 2]]
[[4 0 2]
 [4 0 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [3 3 0]
 [3 2 2]]
[[4 0 2]
 [4 0 0]
 [3 2 2]
 [1 1 2]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]]
```

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer. May be i didnt explained well the problem. As an output i need 3 arrays with 2 rows in each array been substituted by 1´s. Like this:[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [6 3 4]
 [2 9 3]
 [6 9 2]
 [8 1 0]]
[[3 2 8]
 [3 8 5]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [6 9 2]
 [8 1 0]]
[[3 2 8]
 [3 8 5]
 [6 3 4]
 [2 9 3]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]]

Comment: @yndolokoppavel, I've updated the answer accordingly.